# Swift 4 Page Controll Watcher

Tags: ios, swift

I'm using xcode 9.1 and swift 4.
I have 2 Buttons in my View Controller, and i want their colors changed when my carousel page is changed.
Here's my code but it.
I want it to check every time my carousel Scrolls.
is there any "OnPageControl" Methods in swift 4?

Here's my code ( in viewDidLoad ) :

```
    if (self.carousel.pageControl.currentPage == 0)
    {
        self.registerButton.layer.borderColor = UIColor(red:68/255.0, green:180/255.0, blue:194/255.0, alpha: 1.0).cgColor
        self.loginButton.layer.backgroundColor = UIColor(red:68/255.0, green:180/255.0, blue:194/255.0, alpha: 1.0).cgColor
        NSLog("1")
    }

    else if (self.carousel.pageControl.currentPage == 1)
    {
        self.registerButton.layer.borderColor = UIColor(red:139/255.0, green:21/255.0, blue:21/255.0, alpha: 1.0).cgColor
        self.loginButton.layer.backgroundColor = UIColor(red:139/255.0, green:21/255.0, blue:21/255.0, alpha: 1.0).cgColor
        NSLog("2")
    }

    else if (self.carousel.pageControl.currentPage == 2)
    {
        self.registerButton.layer.borderColor = UIColor(red:174/255.0, green:135/255.0, blue:46/255.0, alpha: 1.0).cgColor
        self.loginButton.layer.backgroundColor = UIColor(red:174/255.0, green:135/255.0, blue:46/255.0, alpha: 1.0).cgColor
        NSLog("3")
    }
```

Comment: Is your carousel subclass of `UIPageViewController`?

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing like a UIPageControlDelegate but `UIScrollViewDelegate` offers `scrollViewDidScroll` for that purpose. Using `scrollView.contentOffset.x` you can get the current page, assign it to the `pageControl.currentPage` and update your buttons there.